# In which order jobs will be executed in Laravel queue?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, asynchronous, queue

Laravel queue is async or sync? For example, if i add 2 jobs, how it will be executed?

1) Sync:

```
job #1 started
job #1 finished
job #2 started
job #2 finished
```

2) Or async:

```
job #1 started
job # 2 started
job #1 finished
job #2 finished
```

If it sync, how can i make it async (like in 2)

Answer (score 6):

Laravel's queue system allows for several workers, which means you can run tasks in parallel, but each worker will be assigned jobs synchronously. If you have only one worker running, it will process one job at a time only.

The easiest way to get the queue processed in the order you want is to use multiple queue names, e.g. "high", "low", "medium", etc., and then tell your workers to process them in order - for instance like this:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=high,low
```

Answer (score 0):

use supervisor 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration

#### config Example:

```
[program:queue-work]
process_name=%(process_num)s
command=/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan queue:work --queue=worker,default --sleep=1 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/storage/logs/queue_work.log
```